# Extending the XHTML DTD to use special chars in ID attributes

Tags: xml, templates, xhtml, dtd, template-engine

I want to validate XML templates that are a XHTML extension. Now there are special characters like `{` and `|` in ID attributes. Is it possible to extend the XHTML DTD to overwrite the restriction to the characters allowed in the ID attribute? Or are the characters defined by the XML specification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use the characters '{' and '|' directly in id attributes because in the [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/) it says

> Values of type ID must match the Name production. A name must not appear more than once in an XML document as a value of this type; i.e., ID values must uniquely identify the elements which bear them.

The name production is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Name).  If you expand the syntax rule you see that the only characters allowed in a name are given by these productions:

> [4]       NameStartChar      ::=      ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
>
> [4a]      NameChar       ::=      NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]

Unfortunately the left brace and the pipe are not allowed.  The codepoints for those characters are #7B and #7C respectively; not in the accepted character ranges.

TL;DR: the legal characters for ID attributes are owned by the XML spec and your two characters are not legal.

**ADDENDUM**

Here are some examples.  The following document passes validation for XHTML on the W3C validation site:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>A title</title>
  </head>
  <body id="anid">
  </body>
</html>
```

but the following will not

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>A title</title>
  </head>
  <body id="ani{d">
  </body>
</html>
```

We get the error:

```
Line 8, Column 16: character "{" is not allowed in the value of attribute "id"
```

Now it's rather interesting that if you really want the left curly bracket in the id name, you can *try* this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>A title</title>
  </head>
  <body id="ani&#x7B;d">
  </body>
</html>
```

But you get the *same* error!  You might want to try this; the validator shows the line with the ampersand hash x seven b semicolon but it thinks there is a left brace there.

The bottom line is that you simply **cannot** have ids with characters other than those allowed by the XML specification.

Comment: Thank you! So I have to rename the attribute.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid you will have to rename them.  I added a couple sample validations to my answer to show that you can't even defeat the validator by attempting to use character entities.  The spec is the spec. :)

Comment: Another solution would been to use another attribute name... But you may want to have ID's to get clicks with hashtags to work as expected.